# How to use 1.2 TLS version in .NET for getting authenticated to EWS Server

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

First of am very newbie to C# development and trying to switch the authentication from basic to oauth based one. However while testing below code I got depreciated exception.

#Implementation

```
  // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client
            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)      //client Id
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .Build();
            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
            try
            {
                // Get token
                var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                this.token = authResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
            }
```

#Exception

```
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=AADSTS1002016: You are using TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the security posture of Azure AD. Your TenantID is: 9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf. Please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2161187 and conduct needed actions to remediate the issue. For further questions, please contact your administrator.
Trace ID: 57531a5a-2797-4f77-bc73-11b1e4355800
Correlation ID: 4295ecdd-7aa1-458f-8e6a-03fda78ec30f
Timestamp: 2022-07-25 03:32:33Z
  Source=Microsoft.Identity.Client
```

I tried using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`

Unfortunately this not working. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could navigate for resolving above exception.

Comment: Remove TLS 1.0 and 1.1.  Should be : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: I tried that as well

Comment: Which exact version and build number of Windows and .Net? Do *not* specify `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, this would mean you have to change it again for TLS 1.3. Instead update the system default

Comment: Are you getting same exception message?  You could use either 1.2 or 1.3 : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;  The error message should change since you now are using the proper TLS version(s).

Comment: I used a TLS checker (https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test) on https://outlook.office365.com/.default and I can see that only TLS version 1.2 is enabled. So, to second @jdweng, I think you should attach your exception message after using SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 only

Comment: @MuhammadAli : The client chooses TLS versio0n.  Not server.  If client sends wrong version of TLS than connection will fail.  Also not all Outlook server are the same.  Most have SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS1.1 disabled.  But some may require TLS 1.2. other TLS 1.3, and some will use either.

Comment: @jweng Please stop recommending [poor practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca5386), it's going to cause more pain down the road with the move to TLS 1.3. It's the operating system and .NET version that needs fixing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could help :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Add this line where your code launch (the line must be reached as soon as possible), and don't borther adding `| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`

It worked for me.